# Mocking a static method call inside iterator using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, for-loop, mockito, powermockito

I am totally new to this. Pardon me for my primitive knowledge about the same.
So, this is the piece of code I am testing

```
private static void updateRules(String id) throws IOException {
    // Make list
    List<String> select = Arrays.asList(
            ID,
            NAME,
            APP_RULES,
            RULE_CONFIG);
    // Fetch list
    List<Map<String, Object>> entries = StaticUtil.list(select, id);
    // Iterate over the entries
    for (Map<String, Object> obj : entries) {
        // Call create
        CreateStaticUtils.create();
    }
}
```

I am trying to mock this function's behavior,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticUtil.class)
class MyTest {    
    private Iterator<String> listIterator;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public final void testUpdateRules() throws IOException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticUtil.class);
        PowerMockito
        .when(StaticUtil.list(Mockito.anyListOf(String.class),
                Mockito.anyString()))
        .thenReturn(Mockito.anyList());
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1));
        
        listIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
        when(listIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(<**Confused here**>)
    }
```

Am I not sure how to validate `CreateStaticUtils.create() call inside the iterator`.

**How to mock and validate the same interaction inside?**

Also, do I have to put that also as `@PrepareForTest(CreateStaticUtils.class)`?

Please help me with the same?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to mock it? If the static method (class) implementation is not in external API, you can surely create an instance of tested class in this test or any factory for creating this instance, and just testing it like normal functionality, without mocks